# Getting unique values from Range - how to remove #N/A value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that gets the unique values from column B.

```
Dim lastrow as Long
dim var2 as variant
dim obj2 as Object
set obj2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    var2 = Application.Transpose(Range([B2], Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)))

    For lastRow = 2 To UBound(var2, 1)
        obj2(var2(lastRow)) = 1

    Next
    Range("C1:C" & obj.count) = Application.Transpose(obj2.keys)
```

And I have this data:

[image]

Then I would paste the unique values in Column C. But the output in Column C includes a value of `#N/A`. Is there any way to exclude the `#N/A` being displayed in column C?

Comment: I can't believe I messed that up.  You are correct to use Transpose.   The only thing I see wrong with your code is `obj.count` should be `obj2.count`.   `#N/A` is caused by the range size being bigger then the array.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Yep. That's my mistake. Anyway, is there any way to clear the contents of the array? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean empty the dictionary? Or clear column C?

Comment: @ThomasInzina to empty the dictionary so that if i run it again for another criteria, the previous one will not be included .. Thanks.

Comment: Use obj2.RemoveAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `Dictionary` you can achieve the objective by using the `RemoveDuplicates` method of a `Range` after making a copy of the source `Range`. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = Sheet1.Range("B2", Sheet1.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Range("C2")

    CopyUniqueValues rngSource, rngTarget

End Sub

Sub CopyUniqueValues(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range)

    'copy source to target
    rngSource.Copy rngTarget

    'extend target range
    Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, 1)

    'remove duplicates
    rngTarget.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```